# Retrieving rows with the highest value

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have this query which returns all rows from a table:

```
select Cost, Name, Id
from #Table
```

It returns a result set that looks like this:

```
Cost   Name    Id
----   ----   ----
-2.00  Item1  1 
4.00   Item2  1 
6.00   Item3  1 
3.00   Item1  2
9.00   Item4  2
```

What I want to do is grab a row from each ID with the highest value, so the 5 results become two results:

```
Cost   Name    Id
----   ----   ----
6.00   Item3  1 
9.00   Item4  2
```

6.00 is the highest Cost from the Id of 1, and 9.00 is the highest cost from the Id of 2.

How would I change the query to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
select id, max(cost) MaxCost FROM #Table group by ID
```

to get the item name, you will need to join the result from this to the original, but remember, that there might be more than 1 set of original values for the combination found.

Comment: Wow, I suck. Didn't realize it was that simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
select max(cost) Cost, Name, Id
FROM #Table 
group by ID, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

select max(cost),name from tablename group by id,name